# how to add a red string to a word 2010 addin in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm kinda new to building word add-ins with C# and I have a question that regards strings and font colors. I want to add a red string to an existing string in a cell on word 2010,
something like this:

```
 Word.Range r = document.Range(0, 0);
 r.Text = "text";
 r.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdRed;
 tbl.Cell(RowNum, RightColumn).Range.Text += r;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured something out, I did this:

```
 int TblRng = tbl.Cell(RowNum,   RightColumn).Range.End;
 Range r = document.Range(TblRng-1, TblRng+1);
 r.Text = Final;
 r.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdRed;
```

`int TblRng = tbl.Cell(RowNum,   RightColumn).Range.End;` - this defined the new range at the end of the location where I needed to add the red string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an existing string with new red then use bellow code

```
 object findText = stringText;
                        if (Range.Find.Execute(ref findText))
                        {
                            Range.Text = NewString; // replace old string with New
                            Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorRed; // Set color of the string
                        }
```